# No badge for taking the Stack Exchange tour?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange.com, tour

While looking for a new Stack Exchange site to join, I noticed there is a tour here: https://stackexchange.com/tour

But what was my deception, after having carefully taken the whole tour, to discover there was no reward for doing that. The usual sentence was missing:

> In fact, you've already earned a badge:
>
> [informed](/questions/tagged/informed)   Read the entire tour page

This is simply unbelievable. Inadmissible. Unforgivable.

Isn't there something that can be done to stop that nonsense?

---

<sup>;)</sup>

Comment: There's not really any concept of badges connected to your global stack exchange account though. One couldn't earn a badge on that page. You've filed this as a [bug], but I suspect it's going to be [tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: I know that @doppelgreener. But from the general tone of the question, I thought it would be obvious that was a "second degré" question (https://www.reddit.com/r/paris/comments/3u1yfr/french_humor_vs_american/) looking for "alternate" answers. Maybe we could have a **hat** for reading the tour?

Comment: Oh, no, the humor in the question is clear to me. Filing it as a [bug] categorises it as a genuine bug report though (it enters a development bug tracker in some way), and it looks like we're both aware it isn't/wouldn't be one of those—I've retagged it as discussion. Hats are exclusively during Winterbash, but maybe there could be a Winterbash tour hat?

Comment: @doppelgreener this can be easily marked as by-design though. No harm marking it as a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It reads to me like that isn't Sylvian's actual intention though, to report this as a bug, and instead they intend for a discussion about what this page could give us instead to right this badgeless injustice. Discussion would reflect that.

Comment: Indeed, [tag:discussion] suits better with my intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is simply unbelievable. Inadmissible. Unforgivable.

I agree. But, I don't think it's likely that we'll ever develop `stackexchange.com` into a site that has mechanics for its own badges, though the idea is pretty interesting. But we don't want you to walk away feeling like your hard work at reading the tour went unrecognized, so I made this for you:

[image]

You can actually print that out if you want, and pin it on with one of those laminated ID pouches, or wait for an upcoming swag giveaway where we may or may not be featuring cool ID lanyards as part of the prize pack.

But until then, you and *everyone else* affected by this travesty can find solace in the above image, because *we made it just for you, because we wuv you and want you to be happy.*

In related news: It's still Friday in Iceland.

Comment: I expected "Made with Cheese", but this is good enough. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought you knew: my hearts are _always_ made of cheese.

Comment: Thank you VERY much @TimPost!

Answer (score 6):

stackexchange.com is not a Q&A site. It has no reputation and no badges. It only serves as kind of "portal" to the rest of Stack Exchange network of sites.

The profile linked there is known as "network profile" and aggregates information from all associated sites.

Hence, this is totally a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) case.